# App display does not fill iPad screen

Tags: xcode, ipad, autolayout

I'm converting an app that I made for iPhone to be used on iPad. Using constraints on the Xcode 6 storyboard is killing me right now.

With my rep score I can't post an image of what I'm getting, but basically even when I set the constraints and the placement of the object (a UIView) on a storyboard sized for iPad, all the objects on the viewController fill only the top/left area of the screen.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

-- when you change size of view, other view will be auto change to {0,0,0,0}, isn't ?
but it doesn't change in the right panel. 
it is your storeboard files some settings have some wrong.

Demo test link http://www.cocoachina.com/bbs/job.php?action=download&aid=80409

[image]

Check for those points:

[image]

hope this can help you.